# Unable to install wifi drivers in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 16.04, intel

I have recently updated to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I have a resource CD for WiFi drivers but it says unable to mount in Archive Manager. I cannot also install the Broadcom in Software Updates as I am unable to access it. how to enable WiFi on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS? It uses proprietory Intel Builtin Firmware when I check for additional drivers.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` Welcome to askubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem:
My result:

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:0806]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci